# scaping metrics from multiple replicas in prometheus

Tags: docker, nginx, prometheus

I have a little swarm cluster with 6 nodes and I deploy 2 replicas of nginx on it:

```
  nginx:
    image: registry:5000/nginx:2
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
```

Now I wanna scape metrics from every replica and add it to grafana dashboard, is it possible ? I already tried nginx-exporter but it cant connect to correct replica coz of service hostname issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus service discovery with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803245/prometheus-service-discovery-with-docker-compose)