# Prometheus dynamic targets

Tags: prometheus

I'm using docker containers to create several containers to the same image.
I want every container to be added to prometheus dynamically, they all have the same image name and started with the ip: 10.100.0.x,when x differs them from one to another.

For example in prometheus.yml, I want to prevent from specify every one of them:

```
- job_name: "bla"
  static_configs:
    - targets:['10.100.0.1','10.100.0.2',.....]
```

I tried to read here : https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/
but didn't succeed to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add details to your question that clarify "didn't succeed". What happened? What didn't happen that you expected to. What results did you receive|expect? Your title says "dynamic targets" but you provide a static (not dynamic) list of `targets`. Which do you want?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803245/prometheus-service-discovery-with-docker-compose/70804269