# How can I configure Prometheus to dynamically target Docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana

I'm running Prometheus along with Docker Compose. I want to run n replicas of a given container and scrape them with Prometheus.

In `prometheus-config.yml` I configured the `scrape_configs` the following way:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: cadvisor
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - cadvisor:8080
  - job_name: myjob
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - my-container-name-1:8008
      - my-container-name-2:8008
      - my-container-name-3:8008
               ...
      - my-container-name-<n>:8008
```

How can I modify it so that all the n replicas are discovered without having to explicitly list their n names?

I know there exists a Docker discovery service in Prometheus that should solve this issue. Tried to refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803245/prometheus-service-discovery-with-docker-compose) and the docker_sd_config [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#docker_sd_config). Haven't yet found a way to make it work.

Tried

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: myjob
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names:
          - my-service-name  # goes here
        type: A
        port: 80
```

and it only got to scrape one instance of the service and not the n containers.

Also tried

```
- job_name: myjob
    docker_sd_configs:
      - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock # You can also use http/https to connect to the Docker daemon.
```

but didn't find the running docker containers.